# SeleniumGrid - file upload fails while running remotely

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

The following command executes correctly when running on local:

```
String fileLocation = "/Users/local/file.xlsx";
chro.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='input']")).sendKeys(fileLocation);
```

But fails when running remotely (on selenium grid) with following exception: `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found : /Users/local/file.xlsx`

Does anyone know what might be the reason?

Comment: `/Users/local/file.xlsx` doesn't exist on the remote node... it's a local path.

Comment: Is there a way to wrap the file and pass it onto this specific node?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you are getting, it seems that the path `/Users/local/file.xlsx` is not present on the server you are executing the script on.

To fix the issue, you can make a `folder` named `exceldata` inside your  automation project and inside that folder you can insert your test data excel sheet `file.xlsx` and then you can set the path using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` (which gives the project directory path on the current system) and then you can set the xlsx path by using:

```
String fileLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/exceldata/file.xlsx";
```

Now, the above `fileLocation` is not dependent of the machine you are running the script on and can be used anywhere independently.

Comment: I should've been more descriptive...

My project structure precisely follows your suggestion. I have a dedicated folder containing test files within workspace and use system property to derive it's location. What I was referring to above is a case where my local box was running a set against remote: local -> grid.

Comment: Just found the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244627/9336888

TLDR: use FileDetector to send your file over the wire.
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), options);
    ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - stackoverflow.com/a/16244627/9336888

TLDR: use FileDetector to send your file over the wire.

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), options); 
((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```